# Gerar relatório entre duas datas com php e mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou quebrando a cabeça já há algum tempo e preciso de ajuda.
Tenho um código que recupera uma data do bd e compara a diferença de dias dessa data com o dia de hoje.

Se essa diferença for menor que 7 o registro semanal recebe um valor e se for menor que 30 o mensal recebe um valor.

Segue o código:

```
    $total_litros_semanal = 0;
  $total_litros_mensal = 0;

    $now = time(); // Data atual

    $abastecimento = "SELECT * from abastecimento ";
    $abastecimento .= "WHERE id_secretaria = '1'"; //mudar conforme o id da secretaria
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao,$abastecimento);
    if(!$query) {
      die("Falha na consulta ao banco");
    }
    while ($exibir = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $your_date = strtotime($exibir["data_abastecimento"]);
      $datediff = $now - $your_date;
      $diferenca = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
      if($diferenca<=30){
        $total_litros_mensal += $exibir["quantidade_litros"];
      }
      if($diferenca<=7){
        $total_litros_semanal += $exibir["quantidade_litros"];
      }
    }
```

O único problema é que com esse código eu pego os últimos 7 dias e no caso eu quero que acrescente somente se tivermos começado uma nova semana, ou seja, a partir de domingo começa uma nova semana.

Se o dia for antes do último domingo ele não adiciona, somente se for essa semana, mesma coisa pro mês.

Se a data estiver no mês anterior então não adiciona, porém, estou amarrado em como fazer isso.

**Obs:** estou usando php + Mysqli procedural.

Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Caso ajude, possa verificar o dia da semana, e adicionar um `if` verificando se é domingo, eu utilizei algo parecido para um sistema de vagas.

Vou postar um código abaixo ve se ajuda, caso não eu tento fazer com sua lógica.

```
echo 'Proximo dia util: '. date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 day')) ."<br>";
$domingo = 0;
$segunda =1;
$terça =2;
$quarta=3;
$quinta=4
$sexta = 5;
$sabado = 6;// sabado 6ºdia - fim da semana


$tx=0;
$ty=0;

$dia_atual=date('w'); //pego o dia atual
$data_atual = date('d/m/Y'); //armazena a data atual
$dias = $sabado - $dia_atual;//verifica quantos dias falta pro sabado

if ($dia_atual == $sexta){
    $data_next = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+3 day'));
}else if ($dia_atual == $sabado){
    $data_next = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+2 day'));
}else if ($dia_atual == $domingo or $dias > 0){
    $data_next = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
}

$inicio = strtotime("-$dia_atual days");
$fim = strtotime("+$dias days");
$ini_sem =date('d/m/Y',$inicio); //data inicial DIA UTIL(domingo)
$fim_sem = date('d/m/Y',$fim); //data final PROXIMO DIA UTIL(sabado)
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu entendi sua lógica, só não consegui implementar a ideia ao meu caso, vou continuar tentando